# grammar items with 'the'

Tags: definite-article

The list below is taken from [Barbara Abbott's 'Definiteness and Indefiniteness.'](https://www.msu.edu/~abbottb/def_and_indef.pdf) Why do you think **the** is used before 'personal pronouns' but not before 'demonstrative pronouns' or 'demonstrative determiners'?

I cannot exactly reproduce her list here. If you would take the trouble of going to the actual site and see Table 1, it would be much appreciated.

Best,

Sssamy

---

> - NP type: Pronouns
> - More details: **the** personal pronouns
> - Examples: *I, you, she, them*

---

> - NP type: Demonstratives
> - More details: demonstrative pronouns; NPs with demonstrative determiners
> - Examples: *This, that, this chair over here*

---

Comment: I think it's simply a lack of consistency on the part of the author (as with the use of semicolons and commas in your other question). You can use or not use *the* in either case.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. Okay, it's just that inconsistency is there. I guess I was trying to read the list too precisely.

Comment: Understandable, given the nature of the material. I don't think the author is doing anyone any favors by being less than consistent in the way she presents her material. It's hard enough to wade through as it is!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an inconsistent piece of writing.

Comment: I shall vote not to close. When someone asks a question about the meaning of a singularly opaque writing, we should not blame the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to agree with BobRodes' comment and say this is just *inconsistent writing*.  The first list should have been just "personal pronouns".  Saying "the personal pronouns" seems superfluous.